# PHP image upload - several errors

Tags: php, image, file-upload

So, I'm trying to upload an image using move_uploaded_file(). Here is the code:

HTML FORM:

```
        <form method="post" action="?page=prod&action=register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset class="field-prods">
                <label>Name:</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="txtName">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="field-prods">
                <label>Price:</label> <br>
                <input type="number" name="nmbPrice">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="field-prods">
                <label>Image:</label> <br>
                <input type="file" name="fileImage">
            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" class="btn-prods">Register</button>
        </form>
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
if ($_POST != null) {
            if (!empty($_POST['txtName']) && !empty($_FILES['fileImage']) && !empty($_POST['nmbPrice'])) {
                Product::insert($_POST['txtName'], $_FILES['fileImage'], $_POST['nmbPrice']);

                $target = "img/prods/" . $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
                $fileTmpName = $_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'];
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $target);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting lot of warnings:

```
*Warning: Array to string conversion*
*Warning: move_uploaded_file(img/prods/livraria-print1.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory*
*Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "F:\Programs\Xampp\tmp\php7CE5.tmp" to "img/prods/livraria-print1.jpg"*
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Those are _warnings_ , that is something different than an _error_ ...

Comment: Apart from that: the message is crystal clear, so what is your actual question?

Comment: @arkascha the image is not going to the folder... I need some help with that

Comment: We understand that, since that is what you wrote. But the message you get is clear here: either the temporary file or the destiny folder does not exist. That is nothing we can change. You need to check and fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**# Array to string conversion**

This warning is in `insert` function: you passed array (`$_FILES['fileImage']`) instead of string.

It seems that you want to store address of image, if that so it is better to store the image first then try to save the address of image.

**# move_uploaded_file(img/prods/livraria-print1.jpg): Failed to open stream: ...**

This warning is clear. check your directories and sure that the path you used is correct.

**# move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move**

And this one is because of prev warning.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. I haven't thought about the Insert function...